# Gradle integration with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I've installed gradle 2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04, and I want to run a little Web Application with Gradle, but when I build the Gradle project on Eclipse Luna (I've installed Gradle integration plugin for Eclipse 4.4) and I type "gradle tasks" on a terminal it doesn't show the task "jettyEclipse" to run the servlet.

Here my **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter() 
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath (group: 'com.sahlbach.gradle', name: 'gradle-jetty-eclipse-plugin',     version: '1.9.2')
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'jettyEclipse'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'


    repositories {
       mavenCentral()                                               
    }

    dependencies {
       providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
    }
```

Here the compilation output:

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      :cleanEclipse
[sts]      :eclipse
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:cleanEclipseClasspath
:cleanEclipseJdt
:cleanEclipseProject
:cleanEclipseWtpComponent
:cleanEclipseWtpFacet
:cleanEclipseWtp
:cleanEclipse
:eclipseClasspath
:eclipseJdt
:eclipseProject
:eclipseWtpComponent
:eclipseWtpFacet
:eclipseWtp
:eclipse

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.14 secs
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Build finished succesfully!
[sts] Time taken: 0 min, 1 sec
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
```

And here my "gradle tasks" output:

```
:tasks

------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build. [incubating]
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files. [incubating]

Help tasks
----------
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'me'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'me'.
help - Displays a help message
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'me'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'me'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'me'.

To see all tasks and more detail, run with --all.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.35 secs
```

I also have try with 1.9 and 2.1 gradle versions.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Looks like `gradle tasks` is run from the wrong directory. The output is the same as when running `gradle tasks` from a directory that doesn't have a `build.gradle`. Not even the Java plugin's tasks are shown. The problem is unlikely related to the `jettyEclipse` plugin.

Comment: Very thanks. I was running gradle from my home directory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was executing `gradle tasks` in my home directory, not in the project directory (where I have the `build.gradle`. Peter thanks for your help.